# CASE behavior in INSERT INTO vs UPDATE with bit field comparison to update nchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, case, sql-insert

I'm updating records from a live table to a permanent table and need to compute some values.  Here's the general structure (some non-pertinent bits left out)

```
`UPDATE tbl_static_grades
    SET
        @Grade = 
           CASE
               WHEN tbl_live_grades.Incomplete = 1 THEN 'I'
               WHEN tbl_live_grades.Incomplete =0 THEN tbl_live_grades.Grade
               END
FROM tables
WHERE conditions

IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 
INSERT INTO tbl_static_grades (field-list) (VALUES <values-list>)
SELECT field1,
    field2,
    CASE Grade 
        WHEN Incomplete THEN 'I'
        WHEN Incomplete ^ 1 THEN Grade
        ELSE Grade
        END
FROM tables
WHERE conditions`
```

Grade is an nchar(12) and Incomplete is a bit field.

The UPDATE CASE works with Incomplete.

The INSERT INTO CASE fails whether I use the = 0/= 1 technique or the Incomplete/Incomplete ^ 1 technique with 
"Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value "A           " to data type bit"

Comment: Looks like you dont need the second case. You could just put everything in the else block.

Comment: `WHEN Incomplete ^ 1 THEN Grade` what is this ?

Comment: That's ORing (can't remember whether it's XOR or not) to check that the bit is set.

Comment: why not use the exact smae case?

Comment: It's XOR... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx -- I've never seen that used before.. interesting.

Comment: `SET @Grade =` <- are you really using `UPDATE` to assign a value to a variable?

Comment: Aaron, Yes and that one works.  It's the Insert version that doesn't work.

Comment: HLGEM,  I believe that I tried, but I'm using SET with update and a SELECT with INSERT and the format is different.

Comment: The message clearly says that you are trying to insert an `nvarchar` value into a `bit` column. It only remains to determine which value into which column. But how can *we* help there if the INSERT statement in your posted snippet shows `(field-list)` instead of something that at least *looks* like a column list? How can anyone be sure you didn't simply mess things up if the posted statement has *syntactic* errors: both VALUES and SELECT in INSERT? *Please* take another look at your code. If you aren't sure, post the *real* code here or at least make sure you aren't posting a mess. Please.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the whole operation in one IF/Else block something like this......

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM FROM tables WHERE conditions)
 BEGIN

    UPDATE tbl_static_grades
        SET
            @Grade =    --<-- Also why this '@' before column name
               CASE
                   WHEN tbl_live_grades.Incomplete = 1 
                                    THEN 'I'
                   WHEN tbl_live_grades.Incomplete =0 
                                    THEN tbl_live_grades.Grade
                   END
    FROM tables
    WHERE conditions

 END
ELSE
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tbl_static_grades (field-list) VALUES (<values-list>)
    SELECT field1,
        field2,
        CASE Grade 
            WHEN Incomplete THEN 'I'
            WHEN Incomplete ^ 1 THEN Grade  --<-- Suspicious Code what is ^
            ELSE Grade
            END
    FROM tables
    WHERE conditions

 END
```

Comment: Would you not remove `CASE grade` and just do `CASE WHEN INCOMPLETE=1 THEN 'I' ELSE GRADE END` ?

Comment: JiggsJedi,  I'm updating grade based on whether it's complete (gets actual grade) or Incomplete (gets I)

Comment: M.Ali,  Yes I could do it that way.  I'm using another method to avoid the double hit on indexing.  If the record exists the DB updates it. If no record exists, the DB inserts one, all within the same pass.